# How do I fix polling-xhr.js:503 GET error

Tags: javascript, socket.io

So I've been looking around on google for some time. Trying to find an answer online about my question, couldn't find one. So I came here to ask.

Whenever I have my server send an emit event to the client to pick up polling-xhr.js gives me an error saying that the service is unavailable. With a redirect to line 199. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrbPH.png)

Client:

```js
function LoginRequest() {
  console.log("Attempting to Send Server Request");
  socket.emit("LoginRequest", { socket: socket.id, username: document.getElementById("Username").innerHTML, password: document.getElementById("Password").innerHTML });
}

socket.on("LoginCallback", (info) => {
  if(socket.id === info.Socket) {
  console.log("Recieved Server Callback.");
  if(!info.Error) {
    localStorage.setItem("Username", document.getElementById("Username").innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem("Password", document.getElementById("Password").innerHTML);
  } else {
    return console.log("Username or Password Incorrect");
  }}
});
```

Server:

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('LoginRequest', (info) => {
    const UserExists = db.fetch(`Usernames`).includes(info.username);
    const PasswordCheck = (db.fetch(`Password_${info.username}`) != info.password) ? false : true
    const err = (UserExists == true && PasswordCheck == true) ? false : true
    
    io.of("login").emit("LoginCallback", { Exists: UserExists, PasswordCorrect:  PasswordCheck, Error: err, Socket: info.socket });
  });
```

Comment: 503 is the HTTP response code, which means 'Service Unavailable'. It's an indication that - even though the server says it can do something - it failed to do so. The problem is not on the client. Line number 199 is likely where the request was started.

Comment: @Halycon Yes i can see that but I can't change this. it's apart of the socket.io script. I'm not too sure what the issue is to be honest with you I don't know what i can do to fix it

Comment: One place you could start is by looking the in the server error log. There you can likely find a more descriptive error message.

Comment: There was'nt anything there it only pops up whenever i use the client

Comment: nevermind I got it working thanks for the help tho